# d3js Parallel Coordinates categorical data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, parallel-coordinates

I am looking for a method of adding categorical data to the d3js parallel coordinates. D3js is new to me, I can understand some of what is being done, but have not been able to figure out a way of doing this. Parallel sets are not a good option, as most of my data is continuous.

If you think of the car example, I would like to be a able to filter by brand on an axis (eg. filter so that only data on Ford is shown). I'm assuming that a variable would be needed to define each car (eg. Peugeot, Ford, BMW, Audi etc...)

Here is the car example.

http://bl.ocks.org/1341281

Thanks to anyone who responds.

Comment: You may be interested in Robert Kosara's "parallel sets" - see [here](https://eagereyes.org/parallel-sets) and also Robert Kosara, Fabian Bendix, Helwig Hauser,
"Parallel Sets: Interactive Exploration and Visual Analysis of Categorical Data", *Transactions on Visualization and Computer Graphics*, vol. **12**, no. 4, pp. 558–568, 2006 available [here](http://kosara.net/papers/2006/Kosara_TVCG_2006.pdf)

Answer (score 11):

Actually all you need is an ordinal scale! The axis will take care of the rest.

Check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yFXqj/).

Basically I changed:

```
x.domain(dimensions = d3.keys(cars[0]).filter(function(d) {
  return d != "name" && (y[d] = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain(d3.extent(cars, function(p) { return +p[d]; }))
      .range([h, 0]));
}));
```

to:

```
x.domain(dimensions = d3.keys(cars[0]).filter(function(d) {

    if(d === "name") return false;

    if(d === "colour") {
        y[d] = d3.scale.ordinal()
          .domain(cars.map(function(p) { return p[d]; }))
          .rangePoints([h, 0]);

    }
    else {
        y[d] = d3.scale.linear()
          .domain(d3.extent(cars, function(p) { return +p[d]; }))
          .range([h, 0]);
    }

    return true;
}));
```

And I added one string valued categorical column to the data. I was a bit lazy for hard-coding which property is string-valued.

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what I needed. This should be accepted by the OP.

Comment: Hmmm, on a second look it is regretfully far less brilliant. I would be interested in a solution *using* parcoord.js, not just reimplementing it... :?